# Issues while upgrading related to third party repositories in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: upgrade, updates, update-manager, repository, initramfs

This is the image i am getting after trying to install the new upgrades. I want to go to 14.04 from 16.04, but nothing is happening after this. I am new to Ubuntu and no idea what to do next.

[image: Screenshot]

I have tried the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install -f
```

This is what i am getting at the end after using the three codes:

[image: Screenshot]

```
sparsh@sparsh-Inspiron-3558:~$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for sparsh: 
Ign http://dl.google.com stable InRelease
Ign http://oem.archive.canonical.com trusty-oem InRelease                      
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg                                    
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                                 
Hit http://oem.archive.canonical.com trusty-oem Release.gpg                    
Hit http://oem.archive.canonical.com trusty-oem Release                        
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release                                        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease                         
Hit http://oem.archive.canonical.com trusty-oem/public Sources                 
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main amd64 Packages                            
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports InRelease                       
Hit http://oem.archive.canonical.com trusty-oem/public amd64 Packages          
Hit http://oem.archive.canonical.com trusty-oem/public i386 Packages           
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                               
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Sources                
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Sources                      
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Sources                  
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Sources                
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted amd64 Packages         
Ign http://oem.archive.canonical.com trusty-oem/public Translation-en_IN       
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages               
Ign http://oem.archive.canonical.com trusty-oem/public Translation-en          
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en_IN                         
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages           
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages         
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en                            
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted i386 Packages          
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main i386 Packages                
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe i386 Packages            
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse i386 Packages          
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Translation-en               
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Translation-en         
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Translation-en         
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Translation-en           
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Sources              
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Sources                
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Sources              
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Sources                    
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted amd64 Packages       
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe amd64 Packages         
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages       
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main amd64 Packages             
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted i386 Packages        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe i386 Packages          
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse i386 Packages        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main i386 Packages              
Ign http://archive.canonical.com trusty InRelease                              
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty Release.gpg                            
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Translation-en             
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty Release                                
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Translation-en       
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty/partner Sources                        
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty/partner amd64 Packages                 
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Translation-en       
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty/partner i386 Packages                  
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty/partner Translation-en                 
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Translation-en         
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release                                   
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Sources                        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources                              
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Sources                          
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Sources                        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted amd64 Packages                 
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages                       
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe amd64 Packages                   
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages                 
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted i386 Packages                  
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages                        
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease                       
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Sources              
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe i386 Packages                    
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Sources                    
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse i386 Packages                  
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Sources                
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Sources              
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted amd64 Packages       
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en                       
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main amd64 Packages             
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe amd64 Packages         
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse amd64 Packages       
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en                 
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted i386 Packages        
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main i386 Packages              
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe i386 Packages          
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en                 
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse i386 Packages        
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Translation-en             
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Translation-en       
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Translation-en       
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Translation-en         
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en                   
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_IN                    
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en_IN              
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en_IN              
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en_IN                
Ign http://dell.archive.canonical.com trusty-dell InRelease                    
Hit http://dell.archive.canonical.com trusty-dell Release.gpg                  
Hit http://dell.archive.canonical.com trusty-dell Release                      
Hit http://dell.archive.canonical.com trusty-dell/public Sources               
Hit http://dell.archive.canonical.com trusty-dell/public amd64 Packages        
Hit http://dell.archive.canonical.com trusty-dell/public i386 Packages         
Ign http://dell.archive.canonical.com trusty-dell/public Translation-en_IN     
Ign http://dell.archive.canonical.com trusty-dell/public Translation-en        
Reading package lists... Done                                                  
sparsh@sparsh-Inspiron-3558:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 initramfs-tools : Depends: initramfs-tools-bin (>= 0.103ubuntu4.3) but 0.103ubuntu4 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
sparsh@sparsh-Inspiron-3558:~$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  initramfs-tools-bin
The following packages will be upgraded:
  initramfs-tools-bin
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 264 not upgraded.
6 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/9,172 B of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
E: Invalid archive signature
E: Internal error, could not locate member control.tar.{gzbz2xzlzma}
E: Prior errors apply to /var/cache/apt/archives/initramfs-tools-bin_0.103ubuntu4.3_amd64.deb
debconf: apt-extracttemplates failed: No such file or directory
dpkg-deb: error: `/var/cache/apt/archives/initramfs-tools-bin_0.103ubuntu4.3_amd64.deb' is not a debian format archive
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/initramfs-tools-bin_0.103ubuntu4.3_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess dpkg-deb --control returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/initramfs-tools-bin_0.103ubuntu4.3_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
sparsh@sparsh-Inspiron-3558:~$
```

While i tried the following command

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

i got the following result regarding the unmet dependencies and initramfs

```
sparsh@sparsh-Inspiron-3558:~$ sudo apt-get install synaptic
[sudo] password for sparsh: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 initramfs-tools : Depends: initramfs-tools-bin (>= 0.103ubuntu4.3) but 0.103ubuntu4 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
sparsh@sparsh-Inspiron-3558:~$ sudo apt-get -f install synaptic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 initramfs-tools : Depends: initramfs-tools-bin (>= 0.103ubuntu4.3) but 0.103ubuntu4 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
sparsh@sparsh-Inspiron-3558:~$
```

i dont know how to solve this initramfs issues

After applying the commands i get some kind of error at the end

```
    insserv: warning: script 'K02delllctservice' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Service mountdevsubfs has to be enabled to start service hwclock
insserv: exiting now!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package util-linux (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 util-linux
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

HOW DO I SOLVE THIS ERROR?

Comment: Please open a terminal (CTRL+ALT+T) and enter the command `sudo apt-get update ; sudo apt-get upgrade`. Then copy all the output (select it with the mouse, right-click and chose "Copy" from the context menu - CTRL+C will *not* work here!) and [edit] your question to paste it, using code format (CTRL+K or the **`{}`** button). Thanks.

Comment: while i am pasting the code, it is showing you need some reputations sort of stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**WARNING: Back up all your data before going any further.**

The problem is, almost undoubtedly, that you are using third-party repositories while trying to upgrade.  Every linux distro seems to break when doing that.  So, the solution is to disable those repositories, remove all their software, upgrade, and then re-add any repositories and software you want.  Depending on how broken things are, you may need to just backup all your data and do a fresh installation.  I've dealt with this many times, and it usually comes down to the latter.  The following is advice for attempting to fix things and upgrade, instead of doing a clean install.  YMMV.

First, I'm going to direct you to read these, so you'll have a better understanding of the issue.  Please feel free to do what they say, before trying the rest of what's in this post.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Upgrades
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CleanUpgrade

Now, let's get down to it.

Disable all custom repositories.  In a terminal, type this:

```
sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d /etc/apt/sources.list.d.old
sudo mkdir /etc/apt/sources.list.d
```

There may also be custom repositories in /etc/apt/sources.list.  So, we'll backup the old one and create a new one.

```
sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.old
sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

You should now have a blank document on your screen.  What do you put in there?  To answer that question, to go https://repogen.simplylinux.ch/ and select your country and Ubuntu version.  Then, select the following:

Note: Source respositories are optional, so if you don't plan to compile or program anything, you can skip them.

Ubuntu Branches: all of them.

Ubuntu Updates: security and updates, only.

Ubuntu Partner Repos: these provide proprietary software that can be enabled or disabled when you install Ubuntu; enable them only if you want to.

Ubuntu Extras Repos: none of these.

3rd Parties Repos: No, no, no!  Don't enable ANY of these.

Go to the bottom of the page and click, "Generate List".  Copy and paste the stuff in the first little window into the blank text document, and save it.  It should look something like this, with source and partner repos included:

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
#                            OFFICIAL UBUNTU REPOS                             #
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------#


###### Ubuntu Main Repos
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted universe multiverse 
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted universe multiverse 

###### Ubuntu Update Repos
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse 
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse 
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse 

###### Ubuntu Partner Repo
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
```

Clean the local cache:

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

Update the local cache:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

We're about to downgrade and remove stuff that shouldn't be there.  This might break your system or require some truly in-depth repair.  **If you haven't yet backed everything up, do it now.**

Install aptitude and remove local/obsolete packages (not in repository, anymore)

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
sudo aptitude remove ?obsolete
```

Fix any dependencies that are now missing:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Make sure you still have a working Ubuntu installation:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Install and use deborphan to remove orphaned packages.

```
sudo apt-get install deborphan
sudo deborphan | xargs sudo apt-get remove
```

Again, fix any dependencies that are now missing:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Again, make sure you still have a working Ubuntu installation:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Get rid of anything that's there for no reason:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Now, try to upgrade, again.  Find and re-add the extra repositories and their software, ONLY if you absolutely have to.

Good luck!

Comment: I dont have anything to back up, just got my new laptop two days back

Comment: i am having umet dependecies issue while typing anything to install in terminal

Comment: If you don't have anything to back up, the easiest solution is to simply reinstall using the "erase drive" option.  If this isn't what you want to do, please post a sample command and the output, where you're seeing this error.